# Excel VBA Timestamp Modifiedstamp

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make sort of an Archive out of Excel File. There are **Sheet1** with the List of all Projects. There are also **Sheet2** which contains only "finished" Projects.

I created Sub1 which cuts and pastes all finished Projects from Sheet1 to the LastRow of Sheet2. Works perfectly fine.

I also created this Sub2 (code see below) which should add Timestamp and Modifystamp in apportierte Column for each stashed Project, but instead of adding Timestamp just once per line in separate column, it creates many Timestamps for each copied Column. Can somebody please help me to make this Sub do the Job properly?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

columnHeader = Cells(4, Target.Column).Value

If columnHeader = "Projektname" And Target.Row >= 5 Then


    For Each cell In Target

        If cell.Value = "" Then

            cell.Offset(0, 17).ClearContents

            cell.Offset(0, 18).ClearContents

        Else

            If cell.Offset(0, 17).Value = "" Then

                cell.Offset(0, 17).Value = Now

            End If

                cell.Offset(0, 18).Value = Now

        End If

    Next cell

End If



Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Comment: It seems like "For Each cell In Target" is running more times than expected. i.e. there are more cells in "Target" than you are expecting. Double check what "Target" actually contains.

Comment: Your code is an event, which is triggered by any change, even if it is done in code. So, you need to place `Application.EnableEvents = False` before `For Each cell In Target` followed by `Application.EnableEvents = True` after `Next cell`.